# What does the curve used in Bitcoin, secp256k1, look like?

Tags: cryptography, secp256k1

I'm reading up on ECC curves and on many of them I see an illustration that looks like this

[image]

What does the comparable curve in Bitcoin look like, or are all curves generally the same?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't like the answer.

These curves - including the `secp256k1` curve, *y<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>3</sup> + 7* - 'look' nice when evaluated in typical fields (like the real numbers), but secp256k1 is defined over the finite field *Z<sub>2<sup>256</sup>-2<sup>32</sup>-977</sub>*, which means the X and Y coordinates are 256-bit integers modulo a large number. Curves using such coordinates do not have any concept of continuous lines.

I've tried to plot this curve over a similar but much smaller field, Z<sub>2<sup>8</sup>+1</sub>. Coordinates extend from -128 to 128.

[image: y² = x³ + 7 over Z257, -128 through 128]

Note that even though it may not make sense geometrically anymore, it still has all properties you need. A line (which means, a group of points with equation *ay + bx + c = 0*) that 'intersects' 2 points of the curve, will intersect a third. Tangent again has no geometric interpretation anymore, but you can still symbolically compute a derivative of the equation in a given point, which will have the property of intersecting the curve in a second point.

To show you what you'd get if this were over the real numbers, here is a plot of the same curve equation for that case. Once with coordinates -128 through 128, once with -8 through 8.

[image: y² = x³ + 7 over R, -128 through 128]
[image: y² = x³ + 7 over R, -8 through 8]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the subscript notation with exponents. `Z subscript: 2^256-2^32-977` (I'm learning this as I go along).  What does that mean... perhaps "take the mod of.." or is it something to do with the definition of a field I do not yet understand.

Comment: Yeah, Z modulo 2^256 - 2^32 - 977. Or written differently: the integers modulo 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663. In the simplified (first) plot above, I've used the numbers modulo 257 instead.

Comment: Is there any way to visualize signatures, and that the corresponding "S" value has two valid values?  Perhaps with a different field?  I'm entertaining the idea of educating people about transaction malleability in an interactive demo site.

Comment: Actually **secp256k1 is defined over a Galois field,** not a ring of integers modulo a prime.  Now, it turns out that the secp256k1 field is a prime field and therefore isomorphic to a ring of integers modulo a prime, but this is not true for all ECDSA curves -- in fact, the "sectXXXyZ" curves (for which much faster hardware exists than the "secpXXXyZ" curves) cannot be described using rings of integers.  See this page for an explanation of why every finite field has a GF representation but only the prime fields have a a Z/pZ representation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Statement

Comment: Technically, every prime field is a Galois field. There indeed exist SEC curves defined over binary GF(2^n) Galois Fields, but this one is not. I'm not sure what you're trying to say here, the Galois representation of such a prime field is just GF(p^1).

Comment: Related: I was also curious if there was any way to visualize the rendezvous points that create weak private keys  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/23315/1878  but I suppose that would be difficult or impossible to do.

Comment: @makerofthings7 Those rendezvous points are just nonsense. You can come up with any set of 'special' points and transformations that make those easier to find, but there is no reason why they'd be more likely than others. We also don't actively try to avoid very low number for private keys for example - yes, those are easier to find IF you start by trying to crack those, but as they are not more likely than others to generate, why would you start there?

Comment: @pieter you wrote: "that 'intersects' 2 points of the curve, will intersect a third.".  Image 3 in the original post seems to show a vertical line intersecting at P + Q ... but seemingly not at a 3rd point.  I'm just curious how is the "if 2 then 3" rule applied in ECC.

Comment: @carlcrott You're right - there is one exception, namely straight vertical lines intersect in only 2 points. This is solved by adding a virtual point 'at infinity' to the curve, which serves as neutral element. The result is a mathematical group.

Comment: Since a finite field is just a "wrap around", I am sure we can fit the original real numbers curve over some of those points in the finite field version --
 those points where  no wrap around happened.

Comment: excellent answer

Comment: I’m not sure the comment about continuity is mathematically correct, though I think what you are trying to say is clear. Continuity is a property defined for a function, which EC’s are (not unless we want to use the implicit function theorem and charts). Further, discrete functions (similar to curves over finite fields) are indeed continuous. Perhaps the more correct concepts to discuss for full rigor are connected components or smoothness. This small detail does hinder an otherwise high quality answer in my opinion.

Comment: I believe continuity is well-defined for curves in general, not just functions. But it doesn't apply in finite fields because there is no metric which maps distances to the real numbers, and which allows finding points arbritrarily close to another point. That said, I wasn't intended to be fully mathematically rigorous, only pointing out that despite there not being continuous lines drawn, we can still compute a tangent etc. by applying the same formulas - they just don't have the expected geometric meaning in finite fields, but the math works still.

Answer (score 35):

you can check  the Bitcoin doc https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1 ,
there you will find some technical details about the secp256k1 used in bitcoin.

Below an illustration of the secp256k1's elliptic curve y2 = x3 + 7 over the real numbers (plot using [www.desmos.com/calculator/ialhd71we3](http://www.desmos.com/calculator/ialhd71we3))

[image: secp256k1 plot using www.desmos.com/calculator/ialhd71we3]

in the context of a finite field Zp, which greatly changes the ECC appearance but not its underlying equation or special properties. the picture below represents the same equation in a finite field F17 (the x and y values are integers between 0 and 17).

[image: Elliptic curve over F17]

and here over F59 :

[image]

You will find an online opensource tool here https://cdn.rawgit.com/andreacorbellini/ecc/920b29a/interactive/modk-add.html
which will help you to plot the graphe and to make addition or scalar multiplication on a EC. E.g plot over F97 with P+Q.

[image]

another good article to read about ECDSA in Bitcoin is  https://github.com/bellaj/Bitcoin_Ethereum_docs/blob/6bffb47afae6a2a70903a26d215484cf8ff03859/ecdsa_bitcoin.pdf

> secp256k1 was almost never used before Bitcoin became popular, but it
>   is now gaining in popularity due to its several nice properties. Most
>   commonly-used curves have a random structure, but secp256k1 was
>   constructed in a special non-random way which allows for especially
>   efficient computation. As a result, it is often more than 30% faster
>   than other curves if the implementation is sufficiently optimized.
>   Also, unlike the popular NIST curves, secp256k1's constants were
>   selected in a predictable way, which significantly reduces the
>   possibility that the curve's creator inserted any sort of backdoor
>   into the curve.

Comment: https://andrea.corbellini.name/ecc/interactive/modk-add.html
this is the correct address.

Comment: To help connect a few points, is the finite field you keep referring to also known as the "order" or the "large prime" necessary for the discrete log problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since the underlying field for the elliptic curve for secp256k1 is F<sub>p</sub> where p=2<sup>256</sup>-2<sup>32</sup>-977, and since p is very close to a power of 2,
it makes sense to try to graph the elliptic curve y<sup>2</sup>=x<sup>3</sup>+7 over the field of 2-adic numbers or related rings. Since we only have a finite amount of room to post here, let us simply graph the elliptic curve over a ring of the form Z<sub>2<sup>n</sup></sub>.
The ring of 2-adic integers is the inverse limit of the rings of the form Z<sub>2<sup>n</sup></sub>. Therefore, the rings Z<sub>2<sup>n</sup></sub> can be thought of as finite approximations for the ring of 2-adic integers. Now, we want to graph the elliptic curve in such a way so that two points which are near each other with respect to the 2-adic metric are also near each other on the graphical representation of the elliptic curve.

Let f:Z<sub>2<sup>n</sup></sub>->{0,...,2<sup>n</sup>-1} be the function where
f(a<sub>0</sub>2<sup>0</sup>+...+a<sub>n-1</sub>2<sup>n-1</sup>)=
a<sub>n-1</sub>2<sup>0</sup>+...+a<sub>0</sub>2<sup>n-1</sup>
whenever a<sub>0</sub>,...,a<sub>n-1</sub> are all elements of the set {0,1}. In other words, f simply reverses the bits in the binary representation of an element of
Z<sub>2<sup>n</sup></sub>. Then the white pixels in the following graph are precisely at the points with coordinates (f(x),f(y)) where y<sup>2</sup>=x<sup>3</sup>+7 mod 2<sup>n</sup> where n=9. This picture is an approximation of the image of the elliptic curve over the ring of 2-adic integers.

[image]

Since the field of complex numbers is isomorphic to any ultraproduct of the algebraic closures of finite fields F<sub>p</sub> by a non-principal ultrafilter on the set of all prime numbers, one should think of the finite fields as an approximation to the set of all complex numbers. Furthermore, the field of p-adic numbers embeds into the field of complex numbers, so one may think of the finite fields as objects that approximate a field that contains the field of p-adic numbers as a sub-field. Therefore, it is appropriate to use the graphs of the elliptic curve y<sup>2</sup>=x<sup>3</sup>+7 over the reals, complex numbers, or even the p-adic numbers as a visualization for the fields used in elliptic curve cryptography. One just needs to realize that one is working in a different field for visualization purposes.