# How to determine if a public key point y is negative or positive, odd or even?

Tags: bitcoind, public-key, secp256k1

Take a bitcoin public key (x, y) and its additive inverse (x, -y). How do you identify which is the positive point and which is the negative point?

**Example**

**Private key 1 -> (x, y)**

x =  0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798L

y =  0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8L

-y =  0xb7c52588d95c3b9aa25b0403f1eef75702e84bb7597aabe663b82f6f04ef2777L

**Private key 2 -> (x, y)**

x =  0xc6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5L

y =  0x1ae168fea63dc339a3c58419466ceaeef7f632653266d0e1236431a950cfe52aL

-y =  0xe51e970159c23cc65c3a7be6b99315110809cd9acd992f1edc9bce55af301705L

**Private key 3 -> (x, y)**

x =  0xf9308a019258c31049344f85f89d5229b531c845836f99b08601f113bce036f9L

y =  0x388f7b0f632de8140fe337e62a37f3566500a99934c2231b6cb9fd7584b8e672L

-y =  0xc77084f09cd217ebf01cc819d5c80ca99aff5666cb3ddce4934602897b4715bdL

---

Also, how can you identify which pub key is odd and which is even?

ex: private key 1 x,y is odd , private key 2 x,y is even

Comment: I don't understand the question.  x and y here are elements of the finite field F_p in which there is not generally an unambiguous meaning of "odd" and "even" - every number is divisible by 2 with respect to the field multiplication.  There is a similar issue with "positive" and "negative" since F_p is not an ordered field.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I think Prabu is looking to know whether or not the point was generated from a private key that is odd/even, not whether the resulting coordinates are odd/even.

Answer (score 5):

There is no concrete determination that makes one 'y' value negative or not in an EC point. Feel free to make your own convention, like y-values <= than half of p are negative, and > half of p are positive. That's just a convention, though.

Related:

- [What does the curve used in Bitcoin, secp256k1, look like?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/what-does-the-curve-used-in-bitcoin-secp256k1-look-like)

---

> Also, how can you identify which pub key is odd and which is even?
>
> ex: private key 1 x,y is odd , private key 2 x,y is even

You can't! Not without knowing the private key itself. If you could, you would be part of the way towards solving the [discrete log problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm).

Comment: Hi StephenM347, y-values <= than half of p are negative, and > half of p are positive, please can you explain this clear with some example

Comment: How would one break the discrete log problem by knowing whether the Y is positive, negative, odd, or even? Would it absolutely break the cryptography or just narrow the field search to find a private key?

Comment: @PedroGonçalves Knowing whether the Y coordinate is odd or even is of course not a break of anything, because it's public information. Knowing whether the Y coordinate is "positive or negative" depends on how you define positive or negative (as stated in this answer, you can make up your own convention). IF you define it as "the corresponding private key is even/odd", then indeed knowing whether Y is positive or negative is trivially a security break (you're not supposed to be able to infer any information about the private key).

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this more formally.

Assume that there is a function `lsbPriv(P)` such that it returns the LSB of the private key `k` from the public key `P = [k]G` where `G` is the base point.

Now, we can use this function to determine all of the bits of the private key `k` as follows;

```
func DlogbyLSB(P)
  for i in range(1..256)
    x = lsbPriv(P)
    secretKey.append(x)
    if x == 0 then    ; test the bit
      P = [2^-1]P     ; i.e. we can divide `k` by `2` since the last bit is `0`
   else 
      P = [1]G        ; i.e. we substructed the bit `1` from the `k` and 
      P = [2^-1]P    ; now it is again divisible by `2`
   return secretKey
```

This is almost like the reverse of the [double-and-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add) algorithm that computes the scalar multiplication on the Elliptic Curves.

So, with the help of the `lsbPriv` we can learn every bit of the private key `k`. In Cryptography we call this `lsb bit` as [hard core predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-core_predicate). As we can see, after the 256 calls, the `lsbPriv` reveals the key. So the `lsbpriv` is as hard as to recover all bits.

This also implies that if such `lsbPriv` function exists it is equal to solving the `Dlog` problem on the curve `Secp256k`. Currently, we know that is hard so there is no such `lsbPriv` function.